# cmd string replacement of special character

Tags: windows, batch-file, replace, cmd

I am trying to replace `~` with `%HOME%` in a batch script. This is what I have so far:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set str=%*
set replacement=%HOME%
set str=%str:~=!replacement!%
echo %str%
```

This does not work as I expect, presumably because I need to escape the tilde `~` in some way.

When I escape with `^`, `str` is unchanged. Without escape, `str` is the string `str:~=<my_home_path>`.

How can I change `"~/work/my_folder"` into `"C:/Users/login/work/my_folder"`?

Comment: Knowing batch, the length of the code used to solve this isn't worth it. Is it possible to change the sign to something else?

Comment: Do you know a solution, even lengthy? I need this to call batch scripts from GNU tools that insist on using `~` in paths (even if I spell it out).

Comment: No, and i'm on my phone at the moment, but i'm sure when dbenham wakes up he'll answer.

Comment: Is the possible position of the tilde is fixed? Then you could test only this position

Answer (score 3):

If the `~` is always the first character, you can use somewhat like this:

```
@echo off &setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "str=|~/work/my_folder"
set "replacement=C:/Users/login"
set str=%str:|~=!replacement!%
echo %str%
```

Comment: That worked! The requirement of `~` being first is acceptable, and I can even replace the `|` with whatever I like, e.g. `dummy_string_asdf`. I find it very strange that there is no "clean way" to do that but by appending something before the `~`...

Comment: Oh wait, it's not. I need to be able to replace `~` in the middle of a string, which contains a bunch of command arguments.

Comment: But there is always a space between `~`, so I can use that as the string to search: `set str=%str: ~=!replacement!%` (that is `<space> ~` instead of `~`)

Answer (score 3):

Or a bit more complex:

```
@echo off &setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "str=~/work/my_folder -param one ~ two:~"
set "replacement=C:/Users/login"
call :strlen str len
set /a len-=1
for /l %%i in (0,1,%len%) do if "!str:~%%i,1!"=="~" (set "new=!new!%replacement%") else set "new=!new!!str:~%%i,1!"
echo %new%
goto :eof

:strlen
:: list string length up to 8189 (and reports 8189 for any string longer than 8189)
:: function from http://ss64.org/viewtopic.php?pid=6478#p6478
(   setlocal enabledelayedexpansion & set /a "}=0"
    if "%~1" neq "" if defined %~1 (
        for %%# in (4096 2048 1024 512 256 128 64 32 16) do (
            if "!%~1:~%%#,1!" neq "" set "%~1=!%~1:~%%#!" & set /a "}+=%%#"
        )
        set "%~1=!%~1!0FEDCBA9876543211" & set /a "}+=0x!%~1:~32,1!!%~1:~16,1!"
    )
)
endlocal & set /a "%~2=%}%" & exit /b
endlocal
```

Output:

`C:/Users/login/work/my_folder -param one C:/Users/login two:C:/Users/login`

This doesn't work with exclamation marks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're pretty close already except for a couple of minor problems.

Firstly, there's probably no environment variable in Windows for `%home%` -- at least not on my system, anyway.  I think the variable you're looking for is `%userprofile%`.  ss64.com has an excellent list and description of [Windows environment variables](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-variables.html).

The other problem is that you're delaying expansion in the wrong order.  Try changing your penultimate line to `set str=!str:~=%userprofile%!` so that the inner variable expands before the outer.  Translating forward slashes to backward might not be a bad idea, either.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set str=%*
set "str=!str: ~= %userprofile%!"
set "str=!str:*~=%userprofile%!"
set "str=%str:\=/%"
echo %str%
```

**Example output:**

```
C:\Users\me\Desktop>test ~/.bash_profile
C:/Users/me/.bash_profile

C:\Users\me\Desktop>test arg1 arg2 ~/.bash_profile
arg1 arg2 C:/Users/me/.bash_profile
```

Comment: You are right, I created my own %HOME% environment variable, it is convenient (for me) when I use Bash. You are also right about the slashes, although it does not matter for the application in question (ack). Moreover, I want forward slashes (to let emacs make links of path to files). Have you tested your script and seen it work? It does not here, the result of `ack asdf~qwer` is: `str:~=C:\Users\login`.

Comment: Test it?  Why would I test it?  Pah! .... Yeah, I see what I did wrong.  The tilde has special meaning in a variable substitution.  Add an asterisk before it, and it fixes it.

Comment: No, it fixes it not. It works only for one `~` at position #1, not more.

Comment: With the asterisk, the expression includes everything before the tilde. This means that all command parameters before tilde are discarded. `ack aaaa bbbb cccc ~dddd` gives `C:>/Users/logindddd`. I did find some info about `~` in batch files, but no way to escape it...

Comment: @Gauthier - How bout this?  Replace space-tilde first, then asterisk-tilde to catch tilde as the first character of the first argument.

Answer (score 0):

```
    @ECHO OFF
    CLS
    SET OldStr=~\work\my_folder
    SET NewStr=
    SET Replacement=C:\Users\login\work\my_folder
    CALL :ReplaceHome "%OldStr%"
    ECHO %NewStr%
    EXIT /b %ERRORLEVEL%

    :ReplaceHome
    IF "%~1"=="" EXIT /B %ERRORLEVEL%
    SET TempStr=%~1
    IF "%TempStr:~0,1%"=="~" SET TempStr=%Replacement%%TempStr:~1%
    SET NewStr=%NewStr%%TempStr:~0,1%
    CALL :ReplaceHome "%TempStr:~1%"
    EXIT /B %ERRORLEVEL%
```